# Issue making bootable usb of ubuntu for mac

Tags: installation, usb, mac

I've gotten everything to work up until the 9th step, going by what is on the help.ubuntu.com page.

When it says

```
"Execute sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m
(replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.img or ./ubuntu.dmg)."
```

When I put that into terminal and press enter nothing happens. Granted, I'm not very good at using command line, but any help would be much appreciated.

How it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m
```

`/path/to/downloaded.img`  means path to that img file,for example if the `.img` is located in `/bin` folder then we give `if=/bin/downloaded.img`.

`/dev/diskN` means the usb partition where you are going to place the contents of `.img` file.

Or

You can use [`unetbootin`](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) software to create bootable ubuntu usb from mac.

Comment: so I have

sudo dd if=/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.dmg of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m

Shouldn't that work?

Comment: that's not working.is there any files located in /dev/disk2.please check the name of the file ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso.dmg or ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.dmg

Comment: That is the right file name. That's the file that was produced from converting the downloaded file to an ing file. Also I just did erase on os x disk utilities and formatted the flash drive.

Comment: You can also try unetbootin.

Comment: change the file name to `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.dmg` and then try.